# How to get Distinct and Joins to work in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to get a query built in sql to work with Laravel 4.

It should output 100 rows, but instead I keep getting 850 and can't figure out how to make the DISTINCT work in Laravel 4

```
//I am trying to achieve a result set of 100, which is easily done using sql: Result 100 rows
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, a.brand FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.name=b.name
```

I tried the following but none of them seem to be applying the DISTINCT

```
//But when trying to use eloquent or query builder, the distinct does not get applied: Results 850 rows
DB::table('table1')
->join('table2', 'table1.name', '=', 'table2.name')
->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT `table1`.`name`'), 'table1.brand')
->count();

//results 850 rows
table1::distinct()
->join('table2', 'table1.name', '=', 'table2.name')
->select(array('table1.name','table1.brand'))
->orderBy('table1.name')
->count();
```

Comment: I don't know if `distinct()` can be called as the first parameter. Whenever I do `distinct` selections, I order my Eloquent as such: `Model::select("column")->distinct()->get();` and that usually works fine. Posting as a comment because I don't know if this answers your issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, after messing about I found that the count function was returning the wrong values when both distinct and joins were used at the same time. I was able to check the data manually and found that it was working, only the count was coutning based on no distinct. Not sure what happened there but I have got it working by posting the sql to log file so I can see what it is querying and got it to work

Comment: That's good. I've noticed the `->count()` function does behave weird sometimes, which is why I prefer to use `count($results)`, or whatever you called your php variable. It simply counts the number of elements in the array. Cheers!